# qsub for a Python script

Tags: python, qsub

I would like to submit Python scripts directly on a computing cluster using SGE. I have a test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "hello"
```

I have run `chmod +x hello.py` such that on the front end:

```
./hello.py
>> hello
```

However, when I run `qsub -o out.log hello.py`, the following files are generated:

`out.log`:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

`hello.py.e707589`:

```
print: Command not found.
```

It seems to me that qsub is nonetheless trying to interpret the script as a bash script, even despite the header. How can I fix this?

Comment: It works for me just fine but I found this post after a quick search: https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-solving/147583-problems-using-qsub-pbs-job-scheduler-no-access-tty-bad-file-descriptor.html . Look at the third post, it may be that there is some problem with your shell. You should probably contact your cluster administrator.